# magento 2 error store view error

Tags: magento2

I am getting below error on switching store view.

```
cloudisb_magen13.mghs_catalog_category_product_index_store2' doesn't exist
```

any thoughts on how to fix this ?

Comment: any thoughts on how to fix this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Create table "catalog_category_product_index_store2" manually from another database

Comment: Is it an ideal way to fix the issue ? @BhaveshGodhani

Comment: Yes, It's clearly show the message one table missing, other wise drop database and import again.

Comment: Syntax error near ')' at line 3 15:43:40 SQL command
@BhaveshGodhani is shows this error.